# Square Root of matrices and multiplication

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics

In [David Tong's Quantum field theory lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf), page 101, line 5, he shows that:

$$(p.\sigma)(p.\overline{\sigma})=m^2.I_2$$

(I have placed the identity matrix $I_2$ for clarity)

Then I don't know how in line 10 of the same page he can take:

$$(p.\sigma)(\sqrt{p.\overline{\sigma}})\xi=m.(\sqrt{p.\sigma})\xi$$

As I see, it comes from the formula: (which is used again in the notes)

$$(\sqrt{p.\sigma})(\sqrt{p.\overline{\sigma}})=m.I_2$$

I have $(\sqrt{p.\sigma})(\sqrt{p.\sigma})=p.\sigma$ and $(\sqrt{p.\overline{\sigma}})(\sqrt{p.\overline{\sigma}})=p.\overline{\sigma}$ and $(p.\sigma)(p.\overline{\sigma})=m^2.I_2$ but I don't know how to prove that $(\sqrt{p.\sigma})(\sqrt{p.\overline{\sigma}})=m.I_2$ since to the extend I know, matrix multiplication is not commute.

Note: $p.\sigma=\sum_{\mu=0}^4 p_\mu\sigma^\mu$ where $\sigma^\mu=(I,\sigma^i)$ and $\overline{\sigma}^\mu=(I,-\sigma^i)$. $\sigma^i$ is [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with $i=1,2,3$